# Is it axiom (implicit or explicit) that result of division (f(x) - f(x1)) / (x - x1) for x not equal to x1, is also true for x = x1?

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition, axioms

Please let me ask a theoretical question. According to derivative definition, in accelerating motion (first) derivative at moment t1 is the limit of the function (constructed from position's function) for variable's limit t1. Then is it axiom that this function's limit is the speed at t1? Regards.

Comment: [Instantaneous acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration) is **defined** as the derivative of *velocity*.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA, I mean Constant translational acceleration in a straight line (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line) case [2]. Regards.

Comment: *velocity* is defined as ratio of *space* and *time* and *acceleration* is dedined as ratio of *velocity* and *time*. When we consider them all function of *time*, we apply the rule of the calculus, and thus we can apply *limits*.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA, Indeed velocity is found by taking the derivative of the position function: v(t) = x'(t). Regards.

Comment: @ Cameron Williams, Hans Lundmark, Mauro ALLEGRANZA, Shailesh, Brian Borchers, I'm not in need, just asked that question for get know whether it is axiom. We accept that this limit (first derivative) is the speed at _t1_, but it is only limit by condition _t_ never gets value _t1_, otherwise denominator becomes zero. What then is the speed at _t1_ and how we know that?

Comment: See definition of [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)): thus [Instantaneous velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity#Instantaneous_velocity) at $t_1$ is defined as the limit of the ratio $\dfrac {\Delta x} {\Delta t}$ when $\Delta t (= t-t_1) \to 0$.

Comment: @  Mauro ALLEGRANZA, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity#Instantaneous_velocity there is not definition. It says "we can express the (instantaneous) velocity of a particle or object, at any particular time t, as the derivative of the position with respect to time:". If we define instantaneous velocity at any particular time t, as the derivative of position function, essentially we state axiom that this derivative is the instantaneous velocity. Regards.

Comment: You can compare [Newton's original treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophi%C3%A6_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica#Contents) (notes points to *Principia* text) with a modern one: Florian Scheck, [Mechanics From Newton’s Laws to Deterministic Chaos](https://books.google.it/books?id=H-xHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4) (2018 Springer).

Comment: In math, *axioms* and *definitions* are quite similar (from a logic point of view). In physics, IMO, an axiom is a statement expressing a specific physical principle.

Comment: My answer: It is axiom (implicit or explicit) that result of division (f(x) - f(x1)) / (x - x1) for x not equal to x1, is also true for x = x1. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up, somehow, axioms, and definitions.

On an other hand, you are also mixing the real world and the/a mathematical representation of the real world.

We Define Speed function as being the derivative of the Motion function, taken into consideration that we suppose, by default, in Newtownian mechanics, that the Motion function can always be derived, by the way it is defined...

In an other framework of representation of the real world, for instance Quantum Physics, such notion as Motion and Speed are not defined the same way, and it becomes more difficult to go from one to the other...

Comment: @ Martigan, I mean definition in Newtonian mechanics. Regards.